# 'List indices must be integers or slices, not string' but they actually are integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

As in question title, I've got problem with below code:

```
for index in range(0, len(processed_df) - PERIOD, STEP):
    print(index)
    print(type(index))
    x_samples = processed_df['x'].iloc[index:index + PERIOD]
    y_samples = processed_df['y'].iloc[index:index + PERIOD]
    z_samples = processed_df['z'].iloc[index:index + PERIOD]
    label = stats.mode(processed_df['activity'][index:index + PERIOD])[0][0]
    fragments.append([x_samples, y_samples, z_samples])
    fragments_labels.append(label)
```

Print output:

```
0
<class 'int'>
```

I've tried parsing indices to integers, without success. I really don't know what's happening at the moment and why I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

On the line:

```
x_samples = processed_df['x'].iloc[index:index + PERIOD]
```

Comment: `processed_df` is a list, not a dataframe.

Comment: @Barmar
`type(processed_df)`
`Out[3]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`
so already it's a df

Comment: The message `'List indices must be integers or slices, not string'` refers to the index you're using to access elements, not the element itself. Since `processed_df` is a list, putting `processed_df['x']` means "Give me the element at index 'x'", which doesn't make any sense in the context of a list.

Comment: Okay, you are correct. How can I access it as a dataframe?

Comment: Why on the variables list and in console it displays as a dataframe, while already in code(I printed it in my runner) it is a type: list?

Comment: You must be reassigning it somewhere. You need to post more of the code.

Comment: Are you sure about the type for "PERIOD" and that it isn't messing up your slice?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]